# Facebook iOS SDK Checkin request not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am using the following piece of objective C code on top of the iOS SDK to generate a Checkin request. But no matter what I do, it always return the following non-descriptive error in `didFailWithError()`. I 'do' have publish_checkins permission:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"I am testing checkins", @"message",
                    @"111760725527755", @"place",
                    @"{\"latitude\":\"40.348718\", \"longitude\":\"-73.659047\"}", @"coordinates", nil];

[m_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

With raw url I get following. [Graph api link:](https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?sdk_version=2&place=111760725527755&message=I%20am%20testing%20checkins&format=json&coordinates=%7B%22latitude%22%3A%2240.348718%22%2C%20%22longitude%22%3A%22-73.659047%22%7D&sdk=ios&access_token=x7ExoJHFnamt2oDZiFkNV1i7NGpi4viAGsyCOUPLeXM.eyJpdiI6IkQwRmdvS2pCV05HTXIwNjVPN283eVEifQ.FNxo4rLsloOkapwyCZ_CgAZZcJ_DoKls1f4SnWUuDTVktzLBhFVsjRlKznALx2TUBkXR5wXF3AJPmSC5Hy3MF4mJhPQKRkTQUlXYQebcLJpPkZAHNcszTwWea1TmO_IcB0el7TB9M8TtJcVlKnvzNA)

```
{  
   "error": {   
      "message": "(#12) checkins API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",  
      "type": "OAuthException",  
      "code": 12,  
      "fbtrace_id": "CxcHvZerNp+"  
   }  
}
```

I am able to publish status to a feed, but publish checkin never works for me and always gives me the same "10000 error", which is not clear. I feel like I am following the doc for checks too. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The output for that link was this: {
   "data": [
      
   ]
}
Hope that helps.

Comment: Right. I think that's the problem, but I have no idea what it indicates that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up this tutorial to cover this topic.  I hope it helps!  http://tylerwhitedesign.com/how-to-check-in-using-the-facebook-ios-sdk-and-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the permission for **user_checkins** -->

```
permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"user_checkins", @"friends_checkins",
@"publish_checkins", nil] retain];

[facebook authorize:appID permissions:permissions delegate:self];
```